# Operador Between en consultas Linq (Rango de fechas)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta para mostrar ciertos datos en una tabla, el problema esque necesito filtrar un dato entre dos fechas, pero al parecer between no es valido.

```html
from V in bd.Retardos
join C in bd.Usuarios on V.IdUser equals C.IdUser
join S in Calendario on V.Fecha between S.Fecha1 and S.Fecha2
select new { V.IdUser, V.Fecha, C.Nombre };
```

También probé con esta alternativa

```html
 join S in bd.Calendario on V.Fecha >= new DateTime(S.Fecha1) && V.Fecha <= new DateTime(S.Fecha2)
```

Pero la letra S la muestra subrayada de rojo y con la frase "El nombre 'S' no esta dentro del ámbito en el lado izquierdo de 'equals' Puede intercambiar las expresiones en cualquiera lado de equals"

Comment: A qué viene la palabra `ON`?

Comment: Remover `V.Fecha between S.Fecha1 and S.Fecha2` y probar de esta manera: `where V.Fecha >= S.Fecha1 && V.Fecha <= S.Fecha2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te señalé en el comentario, pienso que la forma correcta sería aplicando la clausula `where`, quedaría de esta manera:

```
from V in bd.Retardos
join C in bd.Usuarios on V.IdUser equals C.IdUser
join S in Calendario where V.Fecha >= S.Fecha1 && V.Fecha <= S.Fecha2
select new { V.IdUser, V.Fecha, C.Nombre };
```

---

Si deseas crear un método de extensión para utilizar `Between`, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
static class Ext
{
   public static IQueryable<TSource> Between<TSource, TKey>
        (this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
         Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
         TKey low, TKey high) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
   {
       Expression key = Expression.Invoke(keySelector, 
            keySelector.Parameters.ToArray());
       Expression lowerBound = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual
           (key, Expression.Constant(low));
       Expression upperBound = Expression.LessThanOrEqual
           (key, Expression.Constant(high));
       Expression and = Expression.AndAlso(lowerBound, upperBound);
       Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> lambda = 
           Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(and, keySelector.Parameters);
       return source.Where(lambda);
   }
}
```

Ejemplo Invocarlo así:

```
var query = bd.Empleados.Between(persona => persona.Edad, 18, 21);
```

> **Fuente:** [LINQ Between Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447926/8933039)

---

Me parece que también te funcionaría usando el método `CompareTo` algo así:

```
where V.Fecha.CompareTo("20190104") >= 0 && V.Fecha.CompareTo("20190104") <= 0
```

> Esto último debe ser probado...